# cascaded property binding using a converter in silverlight

Tags: c#, silverlight, xaml, binding, converters

I have the following problem,

I have a cascade of Items that can be selected by a user.

So for example I have an list of items **A**, an item from this list can be selected and is available via the property **SelectedA**.

Each **A** holds a list of items **B**. Each of those can selected, thus **A** provides a property **SelectedB**.

An item **B** then has a property which is boolean value **C**

Now I can bind directly to **C** by doing somthing like this.

```
Visibility="{Binding SelectedA.SelectedB.C, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}"
```

Now as you can see I use a converter to set the visibility. The problem is however, as long as there is no **A** and **B** selected, the converter will not be used. Therefor the Visibiltiy will still be set to visible.

To prevent that I would be forced to wrap the items in another GUI item so that I can then check for null values of the selected Items.

So I would have to make to wrap elements in this case for **SelectedA** to check if that is null and have a visibility to boolean converter and then another wrap element for **SelectedB** to see of that is also null. Only then could I use the actual element and the binding.

Is there anyway to force the converter to trigger with a null value, so the visibility will be set correctly ?

Comment: Perhaps better to set the `TargetNullValue` and the `FallbackValue` of the binding to `Visibility.Hidden`.

Comment: thanks, I was not aware of that. Could you post an answer so I can accept it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `TargetNullValue` on the binding to provide a default value when the binded value is `null`. You can use `FallbackValue` to provide a value when the binding fails. Set either one or both to `Visibility.Collapsed` or `Visibility.Hidden` according to your requirements.